# Jquery :contains selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, if-statement

I want to run 'action one' when my variables anchor contains the word 'image'. If it doesnt contain that specified text, else it will run action two.

```
var clickedImage = $('.header ul li').find('img[rel="clicked"]').closest('li');

if ($(clickedImage).find('a:contains("image")')) {

        //action one

    } else {

        //action two

    }
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: what is `clickedImage`? we need more context here...

Comment: Created a fiddle and it works for me (safari 5): [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/mAu888/6ZsSH/). If the html doesn't match yours, please fork and provide your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the collection:

```
if ($(clickedImage).find('a:contains("image")').length ) {
```

`.find()` returns a jQuery object. To check whether the selector matched anything, check whether the `length` property does not equal zero.

Comment: I understand your logic but this doesn't quite work. I'm sure what im doing is wrong. `var count = $(clickedImage).find("a").find('href:contains("Walk")').length;` THEN  `if ($(count).length != 0) {`

Comment: `.find()` takes a string (selector) as argument. Omit the jQuery wrapper: `var clickedImage = $('.header ul li').find('img[rel="clicked"]').closest('li')`.

Comment: ok That part was an error so that should not have been there, but the `:contains` part still doesn't work. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Also, you're probably not looking for a `<href>` tag, but the attribute. Use the attribute selector: `var count = $(clickedImage).find("a[href*="Walk"]').length`

Comment: yes I went down another route which didnt require having to have specified text. This is the site I did it on if you want to check out the .js file. http://chantalgillingham.co.uk